# Xdebug with php5.6 not working

Tags: 14.04, php, xdebug, php-fpm

Until yesterday I used Ubuntu 14.04 with php5.5 and nginx, everything working perfectly including `xdebug`.

I then updated to php5.6 via

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5-5.69
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install php5
```

which had a lot automatically other php updates afterwards.
After this xdebug was not working anymore and giving me some shell errors, since it was build for the wrong php version, so I uninstalled and reinstalled it via

```
sudo pecl install xdebug
```

Now I don't get any shell errors anymore, but it's not working correctly. If I disable `xdebug` in php.ini my local server runs with nginx as expected, so the basic setup is correct.

**If I activate xdebug in `php.ini` and request a local page the request hangs as if I had enabled xdebug and set a breakpoint somewhere in my code, but I didn't.** Executing php from command line does work interestingly.

My current `/etc/php5/mods-available/xdebug.ini` look like

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.max_nesting_level=1000
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9001
xdebug.profiler_enable=0
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = /var/log/xdebug
```

and is included via symlink both into `/etc/php5/cli/conf.d` and into `/etc/php5/fpm/conf.d`. Also checking php -m on command line says that `xdebug` is included as Zend-Module.

Shifting the port to 9001 is on purpose, since `fastcgi` is running on port 9000.

nginx log are fine, `xdebug` logs don't exist (directory is empty) and fpm logs only saying

```
NOTICE: configuration file /etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm.conf test is successful
```

Any idea what to do or where to have a look?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Install xdebug in Ubuntu 16 with php5 - error: can't read ltmain.sh](https://askubuntu.com/questions/746742/install-xdebug-in-ubuntu-16-with-php5-error-cant-read-ltmain-sh)

Comment: @Zanna the question you linked adresses a different issue. I don't have installation problems, but configuration. Also the suggested solution of the linked question is already included in my question description

Comment: Oh... did you find out any more about this? Are you satisfied with your answer or still looking for help?

Comment: I solved my problem with the described configuration change, but it doesn't feel like a clean solution. Or rather I didn't understand why that fixed the issue while letting me use xedbug at the same time. Back then I didn't investigate further since I was able to use my system that way without any problems and today I am using a different computer and don't have a chance to investigate anymore

Answer (score 1):

I removed `zend_extension=xdebug.so` from `/etc/php5/mods-available/xdebug.ini` and now I am able to access pages again while still useing xdebug?!

I didn't find any other file where xdebug would be included in any `php.ini`, so I am a little bit confused. Maybe someone else has a more complete answer.