# Install xdebug in Ubuntu 16 with php5 - error: can't read ltmain.sh

Tags: software-installation, php, 16.04, xdebug

I'm trying to install xdebug in Ubuntu 16 with PHP 5 and it fails. 
The command that I use is:

```
sudo pecl install xdebug
```

I searched a lot on forums but couldn't find the cause for this one. Could anyone help me with this?

The following is the console output error:

```
downloading xdebug-2.4.0.tgz ...
Starting to download xdebug-2.4.0.tgz (264,832 bytes)
......................................................done: 264,832 bytes
76 source files, building
running: phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20131106
Zend Module Api No:      20131226
Zend Extension Api No:   220131226
cp: cannot stat 'ltmain.sh': No such file or directory
building in /tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-roottZWTLj/xdebug-2.4.0
running: /tmp/pear/temp/xdebug/configure --with-php-config=/usr/bin/php-config
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for cc... cc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether cc accepts -g... yes
checking for cc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... cc -E
checking for icc... no
checking for suncc... no
checking whether cc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking for system library directory... lib
checking if compiler supports -R... no
checking if compiler supports -Wl,-rpath,... yes
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking for PHP prefix... /usr
checking for PHP includes... -I/usr/include/php5 -I/usr/include/php5/main -I/usr/include/php5/TSRM -I/usr/include/php5/Zend -I/usr/include/php5/ext -I/usr/include/php5/ext/date/lib
checking for PHP extension directory... /usr/lib/php5/20131226
checking for PHP installed headers prefix... /usr/include/php5
checking if debug is enabled... no
checking if zts is enabled... no
checking for re2c... no
configure: WARNING: You will need re2c 0.13.4 or later if you want to regenerate PHP parsers.
checking for gawk... no
checking for nawk... nawk
checking if nawk is broken... no
checking whether to enable Xdebug support... yes, shared
checking Check for supported PHP versions... supported (5.6.17-3ubuntu1)
checking for gettimeofday... yes
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking sys/select.h usability... yes
checking sys/select.h presence... yes
checking for sys/select.h... yes
checking for cos in -lm... yes
checking how to print strings... printf
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... (cached) /bin/sed
checking for fgrep... /bin/grep -F
checking for ld used by cc... /usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... /usr/bin/nm -B
checking the name lister (/usr/bin/nm -B) interface... BSD nm
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 1572864
checking how to convert x86_64-pc-linux-gnu file names to x86_64-pc-linux-gnu format... func_convert_file_noop
checking how to convert x86_64-pc-linux-gnu file names to toolchain format... func_convert_file_noop
checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for objdump... objdump
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
checking for dlltool... no
checking how to associate runtime and link libraries... printf %s\n
checking for ar... ar
checking for archiver @FILE support... @
checking for strip... strip
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking for gawk... (cached) nawk
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from cc object... ok
checking for sysroot... no
checking for a working dd... /bin/dd
checking how to truncate binary pipes... /bin/dd bs=4096 count=1
checking for mt... mt
checking if mt is a manifest tool... no
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking for objdir... .libs
checking if cc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
checking for cc option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if cc PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if cc static flag -static works... yes
checking if cc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if cc supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the cc linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... no
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating config.h
config.status: executing libtool commands
sed: can't read /tmp/pear/temp/xdebug/ltmain.sh: No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat 'libtoolT': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat 'libtoolT': No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access 'libtool': No such file or directory
running: make
/bin/bash /tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-roottZWTLj/xdebug-2.4.0/libtool --mode=compile cc  -I. -I/tmp/pear/temp/xdebug -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-roottZWTLj/xdebug-2.4.0/include -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-roottZWTLj/xdebug-2.4.0/main -I/tmp/pear/temp/xdebug -I/usr/include/php5 -I/usr/include/php5/main -I/usr/include/php5/TSRM -I/usr/include/php5/Zend -I/usr/include/php5/ext -I/usr/include/php5/ext/date/lib  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2   -c /tmp/pear/temp/xdebug/xdebug.c -o xdebug.lo
/bin/bash: /tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-roottZWTLj/xdebug-2.4.0/libtool: No such file or directory
Makefile:213: recipe for target 'xdebug.lo' failed
make: *** [xdebug.lo] Error 127
ERROR: `make' failed
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only supported PHP version in Ubuntu Xenial is 7.0 and php5 packages will be removed before the final release.

However to fix just this bug, you need to fix the ltmain.sh symlink that's included in php5-dev package:

`ln -sf /usr/share/libtool/build-aux/ltmain.sh /usr/lib/php5/build/ltmain.sh`

Or you can use `ppa:ondrej/php5-5.6`, that already have that fix and latest upstream version.

Answer (score 2):

You can also run "apt install php-dev" first before running "pecl install xdebug".

This installs the appropriate dev tools for php7. The answer above is more of a work-around getting a php5 set of dev tools to work with php7.

Comment: For users with Ubuntu 16.04+ using php7 and wanting to install the new version of xdebug which officially supports php7 via pecl, this is the better answer.